# CSS. Как задать border-width?

Tags: html, css, width, height

Адаптирую css стиль под свои потребности:
необходимо задать border-width в 50% от ширины родительского элемента

HTML:

```
    <div class="effect eff-18"> 
      <img src="images/_project_lock.jpg" alt="" /> 
      <div class="overlay"> 
        <div class="icon"></div> 
      </div> 
      <div class="triangle-set"> 
        <div class="triangle triangle-1"></div> 
        <div class="triangle triangle-2"></div> 
        <div class="triangle triangle-3"></div> 
        <div class="triangle triangle-4"></div> 
      </div> 
      <div class="caption"> 
        <h4>Title</h4> 
        <p> Descr </p> 
        <a class="btn" href="#" title="View More">View More</a> 
      </div> 
    </div>
```

Изначально стиль был с захардкоженым значением ширины и высоты, выглядел как то так:

```
.eff-18 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.eff-18 img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.eff-18 .overlay {
  width: 45px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.15s linear 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.15s linear 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s linear 0s;
  transition: all 0.15s linear 0s;
}
.eff-18 .overlay .icon {
  width: 35px;
  height: 23px;
  background: url('http://eisenpar.com/view-icon.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  top: 46%;
  left: 6px;
}
.eff-18 .triangle-set {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.eff-18 .triangle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.15s linear 0s, border-width 0.35s linear 0.1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.15s linear 0s, border-width 0.35s linear 0.1s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.15s linear 0s, border-width 0.35s linear 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s linear 0s, border-width 0.35s linear 0.1s;
  transition: opacity 0.15s linear 0s, border-width 0.35s linear 0.1s;
}
.eff-18 .triangle-1 {
  border-top: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.eff-18 .triangle-2 {
  border-right: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
.eff-18 .triangle-3 {
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
.eff-18 .triangle-4 {
  border-left: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.eff-18 .caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
  transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
}
.eff-18 .caption h4 {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  position: relative;
}
.eff-18 .caption h4:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  display: block;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 42%;
}
.eff-18 .caption p {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: -webkit-calc(80% - 20px);
  max-width: -o-calc(80% - 20px);
  max-width: -moz-calc(80% - 20px);
  max-width: -ms-calc(80% - 20px);
  max-width: calc(80% - 20px);
  margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.eff-18 .caption a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px auto 0px auto;
  background-color: #7F3B1B;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 7px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.eff-18:hover .triangle {
  opacity: 1;
  border-width: 150px;
}
.eff-18:hover .overlay {
  right: -45px;
}
.eff-18:hover .overlay .icon {
  opacity: 0;
}
.eff-18:hover .caption {
  top: 0px;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.35s
  -o-transition-delay: 0.35s
  -ms-transition-delay: 0.35s
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s
  transition-delay: 0.35s
}
```

Начал уходить от хардкод-значений:

```
.eff-18 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
```

Осталось задать border-width у hover эффекта в 50% от ширины всего контейнера

Попробовал вот так:

```
.eff-18:hover .triangle {
  opacity: 1;
  border-width: 50%;
}
```

Естественно ничего не получилось.
Как тут привязаться к ширине родителя не понимаю.

Тоесть нужно сделать как то так

```
 border-width: width * 0.5;
```

Позволяет ли css подобную запись?

Comment: Если размеры заранее известны, то препроцессоры (SASS, LESS, Stylus) прекрасно справляются с задачей (и другой рутиной), другой вариант - сделать эмуляцию (видимость) бордюра с помощью div, и задавать ему размеры в процентах.

Answer (score 2):

Если что, для современных браузеров подойдет такой вариант:

```
от ширины viewport-а
border-width: calc( (толщина бордера)vw / 10)

от высоты viewport-а
border-width: calc( (толщина бордера)vh / 10)
```

пример можно посмотреть на кнопках слайдера на сайте [EMPATIO](http://empatio-design.ru)

Comment: Лучше сделать пример прямо здесь, с помощью сниппета, в котором выполняется код на HTML+CSS+JS. А то на стороннем сайте код может поменяться и пример перестанет быть примером. )

Comment: Я тут новичек, и не знаю как тут сниппет сделать. а там если поменяется, изменю и тут, т.к. сайт сделан мной

Answer (score 1):

`border-width`,  надо задавать не в процентах,а в пикселях

```
class{
    border-width: 1px 2px 3px 4px ;/это если каждой стороне задавать разное значение
}

class{
    border-width: 1px ;/это если у всех сторон одно значение
}
```

Comment: Задача была задать border-width в половину от width

Но как я понял средствами css этого не сделать, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Так можно, контейнер все равно всегда равен 100%, для дочернего элемента.
 `border-width: calc(100% / 2);`

Answer (score 0):

Ничего умнее в голову не приходит, потому что в css нет возможности использовать проценты для `border`:

```css
.wrap{
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  padding: 0 25%;
}
.content{
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Следует заменить `border` на `padding`. По необходимости добавить ещё один вреппер для содержимого.

Comment: Для понимания, нужен подробный ответ с примером(рабочий код в песочнице). Поставил минус.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov, ok, пусть будет. Возможно, ответ действительно к вопросу не подходит, хотя для других ситуаций он годится.